When moving Python app window to 2nd monitor with SetWindowPos(), I need to click on 1st monitor to control the app
I have a small OpenGL app in Python for Windows. The app window is a borderless window; it's not fullscreen. When moving the app window to the 2nd monitor with SetWindowPos(), I need to click on the 1st monitor to make the app process mouse input; i.e. mouse clicks are only captured by the app when I click on the 1st monitor. Clicking on the app window makes it go to the background, as if I had clicked on the desktop. Looks like Windows (11) has a wrong idea about where the app window is.
Both monitors are configured correctly in Windows.
I have no idea why this happens. I mean, when I move the window with ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(), Windows should track that, shouldn't it?
Calling
    windll.user32.SetCapture(globals.displayHandler.windowHandle)

or
    pygame.event.set_grab(True)

doesn't help.
How can I fix this?
Minimal reproducible example (Python 3.11.4, because it comes with pre-built pyopengl and pyopengl-accelerate):
import pygame
from screeninfo import get_monitors
from ctypes import windll, Structure, c_long, byref

class WindowRect(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('left',    c_long),
        ('top',     c_long),
        ('right',   c_long),
        ('bottom',  c_long),
        ]
    def width(self):  return self.right  - self.left
    def height(self): return self.bottom - self.top

class DisplayHandler:
    def __init__ (self):
        monitorInfo = get_monitors()
        numDisplays = len(monitorInfo)
        if numDisplays == 1:
            self.appDisplay = 0
            self.xOffset = 0
        else:
            self.appDisplay = 1
            self.xOffset = monitorInfo[self.appDisplay].width
        self.maxWidth = monitorInfo[self.appDisplay].width
        self.maxHeight = monitorInfo[self.appDisplay].height
        self.screenType = pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.OPENGL | pygame.NOFRAME
        try:
            pygame.display.set_mode (size = (self.maxWidth, self.maxHeight), flags = self.screenType, vsync = 1)
        except pygame.error:
            print ("Couldn't set display mode ({0})".format (pygame.get_error()))
            exit()
        self.windowHandle = pygame.display.get_wm_info()['window']
        self.FixWindowPos()

    def FixWindowPos(self):
        if self.appDisplay > 0:
            rc = WindowRect()
            windll.user32.GetWindowRect(self.windowHandle, byref(rc))
            if (rc.left != self.xOffset):
                print ("fixing window position")
                windll.user32.SetWindowLongPtrW(self.windowHandle, -20, windll.user32.GetWindowLongPtrW(self.windowHandle, -20) | 0x08000000)
                windll.user32.SetForegroundWindow (self.windowHandle)
                windll.user32.SetActiveWindow (self.windowHandle)
                windll.user32.SetFocus (self.windowHandle)
                windll.user32.SetWindowPos(self.windowHandle, -1, self.xOffset, 0, 0, 0, 0x0215)


class Application:
    def __init__(self):
        self.displayHandler = DisplayHandler ()
    
    def HandleEvents (self) -> bool:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT):
                return False
            elif (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN):
                if (event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                    return False
        return True
    
    def Run(self):
        print ("press ESC to quit ...")
        while self.HandleEvents():
            self.displayHandler.FixWindowPos()
        
app = Application()
app.Run()


Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example

There you go ...

I managed to figure the solution myself, but I let this question up together with my solution for whoever might stumble into this problem in the future.
The issue is solved very easily by adding the parameter "display = self.appDisplay" to the call of pygame.display.set_mode:
    try:
        pygame.display.set_mode (size = (self.maxWidth, self.maxHeight), flags = self.screenType, vsync = 1, display = self.appDisplay)
    except pygame.error:
        print ("Couldn't set display mode ({0})".format (pygame.get_error()))
        exit()

So basically you need to pass the number of the monitor you want to show the app's window on to set_mode().
